# How to pass multipart file along with file name to post method using Apache httpclient 3.x?

Tags: java, spring, shiro, apache-commons-httpclient

service code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@RequestParam("filePath") String filePath){
//logic here
}
```

Part of the client code:

```
public static synchronized String responseOfPost(String restUrl, FileSystemResource file,String filePath) {
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(restUrl);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    post.setParameter("filePath", filePath);
    try {
        Part[] parts = {new FilePart("file",file.getFile())};
        post.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=Endedlogging");
        if (file != null) {
            post.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, post.getParams()));
        }
        client.executeMethod(post);
        String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return null;
}
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
```

How can I pass multipart file("file") and filePath("filePath") to POST method in client code? **NOT FROM UI**

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting the exception like FileNotFoundException with nearly same code as your's.So can you try with this change,it maybe helpful.

### Part[] parts = {new FilePart(file.getName(),file)};